# python concatenate ctype struct and array

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation, ctypes

I am trying to implement a custom UDP protocol. This protocol has a header and data. The header has information about the structure of the data.

The header is defined using a ctypes struct and the data using 'h' array(signed short).

I am using python sockets.

I tried sending the header ans data using separate calls to "socket.sendto" like this:

```
s.sendto(header, addr)
s.sendto(data, addr)
```

But I am not able to receive this as a continuous stream.  "socket.recvfrom" is only fetching the header. Maybe if I call "socket.recvfrom" again I will get the data as well. But thats not what I need. I need the full packet as a stream. I think concatenating the header and data in the server itself might fix this.

So I tried different combinations of the following to concatenate the two:

- converting the header to "c_char_p" array.
- Converting the data to bytearray
- using numpy.concatenate
- Standard array concatenation after converting the header to 'B' array.
- Converting header to 'h' array. (This failed with "string length not a multiple of item size"

All the above failed for one reason or the other.

If I need to convert either header or data, I would prefer it to be the header as it is smaller. But if there is no way around, I am ok with converting the data.

Would appreciate any help.

Relevant code snippets:

```
sdata = array("h")
.
.
.
header=protocol.HEADER(1,50,1,50,1,50,1,50,1,10,1,12,1,1,1,1,1,18,19,10,35,60,85,24,25)
.
.
s.sendto(header+sdata, addr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the header struct into a `ctypes` array of bytes:

```
>>> buf = (ctypes.c_char * ctypes.sizeof(header)).from_buffer_copy(header)
```

Now, in Python 2,

```
>>> buf.raw + sdata.tostring()
```

should give you what you're looking for.

In Python 3, it would be

```
>>> buf.raw + sdata.tobytes()
```

Comment: That makes a lot of copies. Using `bytearray` you can minimize this to copying the header and data only once: `buf = bytearray(header);` `buf.extend((ctypes.c_short * len(sdata)).from_buffer(sdata))`. You can't use `buf.extend(sdata)` directly since `array.array` doesn't support the new buffer protocol (thus `extend` falls back on iteration, which won't work since the values can exceed 255), but a ctypes array comes to the rescue by supporting both protocols.

Comment: You could also use `ctypes.resize` to `realloc` the header and then `ctypes.memmove` to copy the data buffer from `sdata.buffer_info()[0]`. While it's closer to how you'd go about this in C, I don't think it's worth the added complexity, and it's probably slower anyway.

Comment: Yep, there are other alternatives too (some working only in Python 2 and broken in Python 3), I just tried to present one reasonable one.

Comment: @eryksun, in Python 2, I get `len(bytearray(header))` equal to zero, when `header` is an instance of a class subclassing `ctypes.Structure` -- what do _you_ get?

Comment: Did you define `_fields_` for the `Structure` subclass?

Comment: @eryksun, my bad -- I had spelled it `__fields__` (habit -- such special identifiers "always" start and end with *two* underscores, so my fingers doubled them up by reflex:-).  I suggest you post your simpler answer as an answer...

Comment: @eryksun,@Alex Martelli ...I could see that both the solutions work. And from your comments eryksun's solution is better w.r.t memory usage. But is it better performance wise as well?

Comment: @kiran_g, maybe, perhaps, probably -- guessing is useless, you just have to time it.  I'd go with eryksun's approach anyway, because it's simpler code, and the bottleneck in your program is anyway likely to be on the socket operations, so a few nanoseconds more or less spent on memory operations are going to be "in the noise", pretty irrelevant; in all such cases (a majority!-), **simplicity roolz**!-)

Comment: @Alex Martelli, As eryksun hasn't posted this solution as an answer, I am not sure what to do. Maybe I will give him one more day to post his solution as an answer and if he doesn't, I will select your answer. If thats not the SO way, please let me know.

Comment: @kiran_g, it's probably the best you can do, and I'm sure eryksun will post an answer since you and I both are asking him to (just wait a couple days, he might be off for the weekend!-).  You might upvote mine anyway, just to acknowledge it's good (though not necessarily the best to solve your problem, which is what acceptance means).  Thanks for trying to live up to SO's culture and mores!